# Sample code in ethers.js to send raw transaction and to sign transaction

Tags: ethers.js

Is there any sample code in ethers.js to send raw transaction and to sign transactions?

Answer (score 13):

to transfer some ETHs you could use the following code:

```js
const Tx = require("ethereumjs-tx");
const ethers = require("ethers");

const sendEths = async ({
  to,
  from,
  fromPrivateKey,
  value,
  gasPrice,
  gasLimit = ethers.utils.hexlify(21000),
}) => {
  const txCount = await provider.getTransactionCount(from);
  // build the transaction
  const tx = new Tx({
    nonce: ethers.utils.hexlify(txCount),
    to,
    value: ethers.utils.parseEther(value).toHexString(),
    gasLimit,
    gasPrice,
  });
  // sign the transaction
  tx.sign(Buffer.from(fromPrivateKey, "hex"));
  // send the transaction
  const { hash } = await provider.sendTransaction(
    "0x" + tx.serialize().toString("hex")
  );
  await provider.waitForTransaction(hash);
};
```

Comment: Stupid question probably but what is/can be `provider` here?

Comment: please check the ethers.js docs - https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/providers/

Comment: thanks, `waitForTransaction` works :)

Comment: This code could use an update, it doesn't work anymore

Answer (score 1):

**Signing**

Link: https://docs.ethers.io/v5/cookbook/transactions/#cookbook--compute-raw-transaction

or: https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/signer/#Signer--signing-methods

**Sending Raw Transaction Data**

I don't know this for a fact, but my understanding is that `provider.sendTransaction()` sends the raw data over. It takes a hex string, and is mentioned under the second signing link above in the snippets.

Comment: Thanks
How can I set the private key for provider.sendTransaction()?
I see here there is not any account info, just provider, but provider do not contain private key, which account associate with provider? Can I change the private key？